# Testing a single sentence with an optional period

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex that tests a single sentence. The sentence can contain any content and should either: end in a period and have nothing following that period or *not* have a period or any ending punctuation.

I started with this: `.*?\.$` and it worked fine testing for a sentence ending in a period. But if I mark the period as optional `.*?\.?$` then a sentence can have any ending including a period and text after that period.

To be clear, these should pass the test: `He jumped over the fence.` `He jumped over the fence`

And this should not pass the test: `He jumped over the fence. She jumped over it too.`

Comment: `.*(\P{P}|(\.\.\.))$`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
^(?:[^.]+\.|[^.]+)$
```

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/lEdiPB/1)

---

`^` - start of the string

`(?:[^.]+\.|[^.]+)` - match either `[^.]+\.` (one or more non-`.` characters and `.`) or `[^.]+` (one or more non-`.` characters) in non-capturing group.

`$` - end of the string

Answer (score 1):

This pattern `.*?\.$` can match the whole line `He jumped over the fence. She jumped over it too.` because the `.` can also match a literal dot.

If you don't want to cross newlines and you do want to match for example `1.2m` when having to end on a dot, or matching only chars other than ending punctuations:

If a lookahead assertion is supported:

```
^(?:[^\.\n]*(?:\.(?![^\S\n])[^\.\n]*)*\.|[^!?.\n]+)$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[^\.\n]*` Match optional chars other than a dot
  - `(?:\.(?![^\S\n])[^\.\n]*)*` Optionally repeat matching a dot not directly followed by a space
  - `\.` Match a dot
  - `|` Or
  - `[^!?.\n]+` Match 1+ times any char except for `!` `?` `.` or a newline (Or add more ending punctuation chars)
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `$` End of string

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/hOnqLn/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use such regex:

> .*?[^.]$

Optional (*?*) means that regex will match if symbol presents or not presents in string

[^.]$ - means that you want to exclude the presence of a dot at the end of a sentence.